# How to move JPopup up to Glasspane

Tags: java, swing

I am putting a combobox component on the glasspane for users to select from a list of items.  When the drop down list is clicked though the JPopupMenu is hidden behind other parts of the component on the glasspane since the popups are displayed on the LayeredPane.

I would like to find out how to make the popup display on the glasspane with the component.  I have tried JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) before the frame was initialized but it seems that makes the popup not display at all anywhere and I am not sure why.

Any advice on how to get the popup to display on the glasspane instead of the jlayeredpane would be helpful.  I searched but most responses seem to related to pushing events down that are captured on the glasspane.

I am actually using a [JideAutoCompletionComboBox](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/AutoCompletionComboBox.html) which extends JComboBox.

Edit for question:  I have a system wide (my app has a bunch of workspaces on tabs) popup type system.  I would like to not use a Modal dialog for this and just use the glasspane.  The component is basically for creating a message but one of the subcomponents is a combobox.  Effectively you can think of the whole component like a popup though, but using the glasspane.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something: Why is your combobox in the glasspane?

Comment: I also don't understand why you don't use a modal dialog. You can always make the dialog non decorated if you don't want to see the borders.

Comment: well, honestly I think modal dialogs are horrible haha.  I don't like little floating windows that users can screw up by pushing around.  I know they block like I want, but I do not like the separate window.  Now if there is a way to limit that and I am just not aware I would be happy to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't like little floating windows that users can screw up by pushing around.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(...);
dialog.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: k, ill try that out.  It didn't stand out when browsing the trails so sorry if its a newb questions.  I just don't mess with popups much :P  I'll give it a try and come back for credit after :)